# Can I connect to Synology NAS DS 215j directly over ethernet cable while NAS in DHCP mode

Tags: ethernet, nas

I want to connect directly to my NAS with ethernet cable and it doesn't work.
I have reset the NAS on reset button a few times but i can't connect to it...
I tried with static IP from my NIC and with Auto settings but nothing works.....is it somehow possible to connect to NAS directly out of the box? How??

Comment: You did set your NAS to use a static IP before disconnecting it from the network, right?

Comment: No...it's now all gone because i hit the reset button :( what to do now? I have an old router and it's in DHCP mode and it can see the NAS but i can't ping it nor connect to it!! I don't get it why!?

Comment: Simply repeating the reset procedure should be enough.

Comment: I have repeated it more than 10 times....i don't know what to do else....i have reset my NAS and Modem and restarted PC...nothing works

Comment: Something is wrong with my modem.... but the question is...is it possible to connect directly to NAS over ethernet with NAS in DHCP mode

Comment: I lost almost whole day to fix this problem and i needed to use another modem/router with DHCP (my old router is not working properly)

Answer (score 4):

Actually it is possible dedicated software:

1. The first time, the NAS is configured with DHCP *enabled* on the LAN1 interface.

   1.1. Using a router, such as an ISP Internet Box, we can connect directly to it with a Laptop and setup it. DHCP enabled will allow the NAS to act as a router, like your internet Box, and the laptop will connect to it as a client.

   1.2. Without a router, it is still possible to connect, but you must configure a DHCP server on the laptop. Free software exists such as [this one](http://www.dhcpserver.de/cms/) or [this one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dhcpserver/). [Here](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/connect-synology-nas-directly-to-pc-without-router-external-dhcp.html) is a complete tutorial to perform this step.
2. After configuration, LAN1 is usually setup with DHCP *disabled* (see pic below). So that we can use an Ethernet cable to connect the NAS directly to the router, an Internet provider Wifi box for instance, and the NAS will act as a client to this box. While on Wifi at home, I use the IP below to connect to the http dsm tool/ssh serveur/web/etc.

[image]

3. My recommandation is to plug a second Ethernet cable in the LAN2 port and to activate DHCP. This will allow to connect any laptop/PC to it directly and benefit from high transfer rates, but we need the cable. In this mode I use the IP below to connect to the web interface.

[image]

To change the configuration of the network ports, go to the DSM interface, Control Panel, Network, select the port and Edit.

Comment: Which synology nas are you talking about?

Comment: DS916+ with DSM 6.0.2

Comment: Ma be you can edit your question and add this information, if depends on the DSM software installed, and the number of LAN ports availables.

Comment: But anyway you mention here "...After configuration"
Imagine that you don't have a router or anything else except your laptop, a network cable and NAS!!! That was the question!

Comment: Yes, the point (1) explained that you can connect directly to your NAS with a laptop and a network cable, nothing more... If it does not work directly, try to do a factory reset

Comment: That is the point... out of the box NAS is set to work in DHCP and you can't connect directly to it with only a network cable. Except if you install some software to mimic the DHCP

Comment: Yes I will update my answer to be more clear. I guess there is no other way. For instance, it is not possible to use a USB stick to boot from it and directly setup the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it got it to work for me with an ethernet cable to my DS214play

1) disconnect wifi

2) Let windows search the network

3) Check network neighbourhood, it should be there

After finding the NAS I could connect the Wifi and still use the NAS through the nerwork name.

Answer (score 0):

I have connected my computer directly to the NAS through ethernet cable, without router, modem or hub. I have configured a fixed IP adress on the computer like 169.254.0.10 / 255.255.0.0. The NAS has assigned an IP like this in automatic mode. Then I have run the Synology Assistant program and I clicked the "Search" button and it has recognized it without any problem.

Sorry my poor english!

Answer (score 0):

I just bought DS218+, after setup etc, I connect my NAS to mac (Sierra 10.12) with LAN cable (using LAN to USBC converter), and my laptop recoqnize it as external HDD. No setting needed at all

I tried this method because I need to transfer mac photos library (100GB), it takes forever using wifi.

Answer (score -1):

Elaborating on Mountrix's answer above...

Take your old router (e.g. BT HH5)
Plug in the power.  Note: you do NOT need to connect it to an active DSL line.
Connect NAS to Ethernet Port 1
Connect Laptop to Ethernet Port 2
This will allow your NAS to get the old IP address (e.g. 192.168.1.xxx), and your laptop to access it.

Worked for me. thank guys.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is NO! It is not possible to connect to Synology NAS directly via ethernet cable if it's in DHCP mode... When NAS is reset, it's automatically set to DHCP mode and it needs to be connected to modem or router with DHCP enabled so it can get an IP address. And then it is possible to connect to NAS and set the static IP address. Both PC and NAS need to have static IP addresses on the same IP range. Only then it is possible to connect NAS and PC directly with ethernet cable and that's it

**UPDATE:**

So I will have to correct myself a little bit....
The right answer would be NO (if you don't install some special software on your Laptop/PC that mocks a DHCP server).

Comment: So the answer is yes after all. ;)

Comment: Not in DHCP mode directly

Comment: @DanielB imagine that you just bought the NAS and you don't have any network... just Laptop, network cable and NAS.... and you connect directly network cable from Laptop to NAS, you will not be able to see the NAS because it is set to work in DHCP by default.... and it won't have an IP address to connect to!